# Jest: How to provide Redux mock store to only the child component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am full rendering a component using `mount` like this:

`const wrapper = mount(<Component />);`

And this component renders a child component which uses React-Redux. I want to provide the Redux mock store to only the child component. How do I do it?

Comment: What's your case? Why is providing it to `Component` a problem? There's no good way to do this, and the problem is likely in a way you test it.

Comment: @estus Component do not use Redux

Comment: Then applying <Provider> to it won't create problems. You're applying at the top of component hierarchy in production app, not to every component. This is primarily Enzyme question, isn't it? `shallow` belongs to Enzyme, not Jest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A store should be provided to whole component hierarchy:

```
mount(<Provider store={mockStore}><Component /></Provider>)
```

This should create no problems if testing strategy was chosen properly. In case parent and child components need different conditions to be tested, this likely means that they should be tested in isolation with `shallow` instead of `mount`.